# php static countdown with filemtime

Tags: php, time, static, countdown, filemtime

A file updates every 60 minutes. I would like to have a countdown for the next update from comparing filemtime with time.

I'm getting a brain fart dealing with time

Answer (score 4):

Both `filemtime()` and `time()` return an [Unix Timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time): the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT. So, just subtract the value of `filemtime()` to the value of `time()` and you get the number of seconds elapsed since the file was last modified.

```
$modifiedTime = filemtime("somefile.txt");
$now = time();
$timeSinceModified = $now - $modifiedTime; //Time since modified in seconds.
```

If you want the value in another unit of time just multiply or divide it.

For instance, `$timeSinceModified / 60` will give you the time in minutes.